# What will be the proper way to delete record from multiple tables using php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using following method but i want to improve it by using single query...

```
$sql="DELETE FROM expense";
$sql1="DELETE FROM invoice";
$sql2="DELETE FROM cat";
$sql3="DELETE FROM conf";
$sql4="DELETE FROM patient";
$sql5="DELETE FROM prv";
$sql7="DELETE FROM test_invoice";
$sql8="DELETE FROM test_style";

 if (mysql_query($sql) && mysql_query($sql1) && mysql_query($sql2)&&    mysql_query($sql3)&& mysql_query($sql4)&& mysql_query($sql5)&& mysql_query($sql7)&& mysql_query($sql8)) {
header("location:backup_page.php");

} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
}
```

This code works fine but when every i write query in single line it only delete record from first two tables and then don't....

```
   $sql="DELETE FROM expense, invoice, cat, conf, patient, prv, test_invoice, test_style";
```

Comment: Are you looking for [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html)??

Comment: @saty No, i just want to empty the tables....

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) might help you

Comment: Bro, If 2 tables deleting successfully in the sense, better change the name of table 3(where it is breaking) or remove the table from list and try

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this?

```
$sql="DELETE expense, invoice, cat, conf, patient, prv, test_invoice, test_style FROM expense, invoice, cat, conf, patient, prv, test_invoice, test_style";
```

Answer (score -1):

Put all table names in an array then use a loop to go through all and write query so u need to write less and do more..

```
    $table = ('expense','invoice','cat');
    foreach($table as $tbl) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FORM '$tbl'");
    }
```

Rest you can manage ... Hope it will help...